# C code to out yes if string contains all numbers, and no if it does contain something other than numbers

Tags: c, loops, char, c-strings, digits

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

char input[50];
int i, hello = 0; // Wish to out Yes if "9999" is input. But why does it not happen?
   
   scanf("%s", input);
   
   for (i = 0; i<strlen(input); i++){
      if (input[i]>9 || input[i]<0){
         hello = 1;}
         }
      
   if (hello == 0) printf("Yes\n");
   else if (hello == 1)printf("No\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your string contains characters, not the corresponding digit values.  Change `9` to `'9'` and `0` to `'0'`.  That way you'll do character comparisons.  Alternatively, you can convert the character to the corresponding digit value first, then compare to the ordinary digit values.

Answer (score 0):

Character symbols of digits are `'0'`, `'1'`, and up to `'9'`.

The for loop should be interrupted as soon as a non-digit character is encountered.

It is better to use a while loop. Calling `strlen` within the for loop is redundant and inefficient. For example

```
const char *p = input;

while ( '0' <= *p && *p <= '9' ) ++p;

hello = *p != '\0';

if (hello == 0) printf("Yes\n");
else if (hello == 1)printf("No\n");
```

You may also use the standard function `isdigit` declared in the header `<ctype.h>` instead of explicitly to compare with symbols of digits. For example

```
#include <ctype.h>

//...

while ( isdigit( ( unsigned char )*p ) ) ++p;
```